# Certain 2fa authenticator apps not working in Keycloak. Any Workarounds?

Tags: keycloak, multi-factor-authentication, totp

I hope you are doing good.

I have a question. We are using Keycloak as our auth provider for our Services, and for some users, we want to have 2fa enabled.

Now, it appears that not all authenticator apps are working. We have done a small test and figured the following table

| App Name | Working? |
| --- | --- |
| Google Authenticator | YES |
| FreeOTP | YES |
| Duo Mobile | NO |
| Microsoft Authenticator | NO |
| Authy | NO |

Question: Is there a workaround on how to get the other authenticators to work? Our Keycloak version is 22.0